# How can i fetch a dynamic Excel (with updating contents) file in order to build an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, html, excel

I will go straight to the point.

I have an Excel file which I built in several months; this Excel file downloads data from the web through queries and then makes some calculation on downloaded data.

I would like to build a website which fetches these Excel-computed data and generates an HTML table to show on the web.

I already have a script with javascript which does the job, but in a static way.

The problem is that I want to automatize all the process on real-time, meaning:

1. the Excel updates data every minute;
2. the javascript code generates an updated table with the new data.

Is there a way to load the Excel file on my domain and automatically update it ON THE SERVER (not locally), so that my js code can show the new data?

I tried to do it in a static way locally.

When the excel updates its contents, the js shows a new table and it's ok.

The thing is that I want the excel file to update itself on a server domain.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please include more details in your answer. What queries are you talking about? How are these queries executed? When you open the Excel? Why not run the queries on the server directly?

Comment: Hello @Grizzlly thanks for answering :) The queries download some financial information about some securities from web, then i compute some calculations through excel. Ideally, the scenario would be a always-open excel file which automatically update data every 60 seconds (this can be achieved simply through excel data update setup). About running the queries on the server... Well, I have no idea on how to perform that :)

Comment: I think one hacky solution is to just open the excel on the server and then terminate the process after a few seconds. Although you may need Windows server for this :).